# Separating externals in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to seperate React & React Dom from just one of my JS builds (server-sitecore) but can't seem to find any examples of this online. Maybe this isn't the only solution.

In my Webpack bundle the entry is as follows:

```
<code>
entry: {
   'server-node': [
       './src/router'
    ],
    'server-sitecore': [
       './src/reactsitecore/index'
    ],
    client: [
        './src/client/index'
    ]
}
</code>
```

And if I add the following externals as follows then it understandably removes the two dependencies from all builds...

`externals: {
    'react': 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
}`

How do I remove these two dependencies from the 'server-sitecore' build?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webpack in multicompiler mode for more control. Basic idea:

```
module.exports = [{... config ...}, ...];
```

In this case you would separate entries into two configurations like that. If you want to share bits between them, you could try a solution such as [webpack-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: This is a really good solution - thanks for pointing out your helpful extension. At the minute your library might be a little overkill as I can probably use Object.assign to merge the objects but later down the line, when I'm sure Webpack config will increase in size and complexity then it will probably be more beneficial.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I ended up developing it. You can end up with `Object.assign` and `concat` all over the place and that's not nice. There are other similar solutions out there as well. No one right way.